# How to fetch and store questions with complex text formatting for an Android app?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am developing an educational Android app using Kotlin that generates question papers for physics, chemistry and mathematics. The questions are not only text based, but they can also contain tables, subscripts, superscripts, chemical equations, reactions and diagrams/structures. How can I fetch and store these questions in a way that preserves their formatting and allows me to display them in the app?  Is there any API or library that can help me with this task? I did some research but I couldn’t find any solution. I'm looking for an optimized way to achieve this.
References:
[image: Reference app img-1]
[image: Reference app img-2]
App link: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quantumpaper

Answer (score 1):

You can try using this **library**,

Markwon: https://github.com/noties/Markwon

You will have to get familiar with the **Markdown** formatting, and you can achieve the following mentioned formatting

- Emphasis (*, _)
- List item
- Strong emphasis (**, __)
- Strike-through (~~)
- Headers(#{1,6})
- Links ( && [][])
- Images Thematic break (---, ***, ___)
- Quotes & nested quotes (>{1,})
- Ordered & non-ordered lists & nested ones
- Inline code Code blocks Tables (with limitations)
- Syntax highlight LaTeX formulas
- HTML

Everything is mentioned on the repo. You will have to format your questions accordingly in the text format, you can search for the Markdown formatters online, that can help.